# Bayes' Theorem problem - Enough information?

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> There are 5000 British people. A British is either an English, a Scott
>   or a Welsh. 30% of the British are Scottish, and the English are six
>   times the Welsh. The probability that a British has red hair is 0.25,
>   while the probability that a non-Welsh British has red hair is 0.2.
>   What is the expected number of Welsh with red hair?

Is it possible to solve this, given the above information?

R = the event that a british has red hair.
W = the event that a british is welsh.
P(R) = 0.5
P(W) = 0.1
P(R|W') = 0.2
I feel like I'm missing information about P(R|W), or am I completely off track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given information, $70\%$ are non-Scottish, so the English are $60\%$ and the Welsh are $10\%$.

Let $R$ be the event a person has red hair, and let $W$ be the event a person is Welsh. We want $\Pr(R\mid W)$. We are told that $\Pr(R)=0.25$, and $\Pr(R\mid W')=0.2$.

Solve the problem informally. Out of say $100$ British, we would have $25$ with red hair. Of the $100$ people, $90$ would be non-Welsh, accounting for $18$ red-haired people. So $7$ of the $10$ Welsh would have red hair. Scale up by multiplying by $50$.

**Another way:** One can also use the machinery of conditional probability. Start from 
$$\Pr(R)=\Pr(R\cap W)+\Pr(R\cap W').\tag{1}$$
To calculate $\Pr(R\cap W')$, use the fact that
$$\Pr(R\mid W')=\frac{\Pr(R\cap W')}{\Pr(W')}.\tag{2}$$
You know $\Pr(R|W')$ and $\Pr(W')$, so you can find $\Pr(R\cap W')$. Now fom (1) you can find $\Pr(R\cap W)$, and then, since you know $\Pr(W)$, you can find $\Pr(R\mid W)$.

Comment: Thank you for providing both an informal and intuitive solution, and a more formal one. That was a big help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Pr[R]=\Pr[R\mid W]\Pr[W]+\Pr[R\mid W']\Pr[W'].$$

You know four of the five quantities appearing in this equation.

Comment: Note that the formula can be interpreted in terms of a probability tree whose first stage contains the possibilities Welsh/not Welsh and whose second stage contains the possibilities red/not red.  You know the result of using this tree to compute $\Pr[R],$ and you know three of the four probabilities that go into the computation.  This allows you to solve for the fourth.